# Update screen only works once and then stops working || UNITY

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, position

So i have a 3x3 gameBoard. The character starts in the middle. When i press right nothing happens, when i press left nothing happens but when i press up it moves to the position in the code.

```
void Start()
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(0.28f, -0.27f);
    print(transform.position.x);
}

void Update()
{
    if (ChrP == new Vector2(0.28f, -0.27f))
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")) > 0.0f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(1.95f, -0.27f);
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Left")) > 0.0f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(-1.36f, -0.27f);
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Down")) > 0.0f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.28f, -1.923f);
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Up")) > 0.0f)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0.28f, 1.401f);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So, for the new "Up" position i have the same type of code and i have checked everything but it just freezes instead of moving.
My expectation is that it is going to check every frame if i have pressed the button. Maybe i have missed something.
Also both after and before the if statement i have the same type of code but for other coordinates!

Comment: I suggest you learn how to debug code, surely this is something that is easily spotted? However, your `Update` method will only ever do anything if the `ChrP` value is at a very specific position.

Comment: @MichelAtwood DavidG is right why do you have that if statement in the beginning

Comment: the if statement in the beginning is too check where the object is located

Comment: But surely the object has moved...

Comment: why do you have an empty else statement?

Comment: If you found my answer worked, I ask that you upvote it or accept it as the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `transform.position` function for your left and right code. You're creating a `vector2` instead of a `vector3` like you have in the up and down functions. According to the [Unity Scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html), `transform.position` takes a `vector3` position, and not a `vector2`. The fix should be simple then:

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Right")) > 0.0f)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(1.95f, -0.27f);
    }
if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Left")) > 0.0f)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(-1.36f, -0.27f);
    }
```